Apache Superset odata integration
Quick question its looks as of now, there is no native integration between Apache Superset and OData? Is this correct.
To get my odata queries into superset seems like I would have to import them into a database first then read from there?
I tried to see if there are any off the shelf Superset plugins to handle OData connections, but alias I haven't found one yet
